# how the CPU start by execution stored in motherboards flash memory chip

Tags: cpu, bootloader, register, addressing

I had read that at start, the CPU program counter register is fill with F000.

I though that:

- PC registers contain the next instruction address.
- This address is send to the address bus and value return to the data bus

Does the address bus only deal with RAM? Obviously the bios isn't store in ram.

So HOW F000 target the ROM to start BIOS execution

Comment: What CPU are you referring to?

Comment: @jippie He refers to motherboards, so presumably x86, but you're right, there are other options such as ARMxx.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, in my case its x86. However don't they share the same logic?

Comment: ARM7 (for example) boot from a vector at address 0x00, so not exactly, but the general answer I gave it correct- it's done by hardware, and must be because there is no software or firmware yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fairly detailed answer on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804724/how-is-the-bios-rom-mapped-into-address-space-on-pc).

Bottom line, is that the hardware has to decode the address space such that the BIOS ROM appears at the appropriate address.

Here, for example, is the original IBM PC memory map from an [online book](http://www.mindshare.com/files/ebooks/isa%20system%20architecture%20%283rd%20edition%29.pdf). Things have moved on since then, but this should give you an idea. The actual decoding logic is the equivalent of gates, probably implemented in some other form (used to be PLDs, but probably a side job of more complex support chips now).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Sorry for the duplicated. Also I know that its the hardware job, Its exactly that I want to learn all the hardware behavior for rom/ram address mapping

Comment: I added the original PC memory map.

Comment: Laster question, from which book this image is from?

Comment: See the link included in my edit "ISA System Architecture 3rd Edition".